# Getting DrawableRight to be pushed to edge of the screen

Tags: android, android-layout

Im trying to show a ListView (Actually a DragSortListView) with a textitem and a drawableRight similar to the iOS disclosure indicator. Im not able to position the drawableRight to the edge of the screen and it always seems to appear right at the end of the text and not at the edge of the screen.

For e.g., this is how I want it.

```
 + Text1 here             >
 + Text2                  >
```

But it appears as

```
 + Text1 here>
 + Text2>
```

I have tried the many layout options and suggestions (since my LinearLayout is Horizontal) but none of them seem to help. The only way I can get to do what I want is setup the layout_width of the TextView to be some hardcoded value, say, 128dp so that it appears positioned at the end of the screen, but that might not be a proper solution since the screen dimensions can vary.

Can you please take a look at my layout code and see what I could be missing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/titleslist_selector_tablet"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText,UselessParent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dragHandle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/dragicon"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_weight="0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/navigate"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#454545"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The @drawable/navigate is an image that displays the ">"

Comment: Have you try to remove your `android:weight` properties from your `ImageView` and `TextView`?

Comment: @G.T. yes, I did, no luck with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like [DragSortListView](https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview) was causing the text to be wrapped due to a getMeasuredWidth not taking the full width as expected. There is a [github issue](https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview/issues/73) highlighting this problem and the [solution](https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview/issues/73#issuecomment-15279734) presented in that ticket seems to solve this perfectly. Sorry for the noise.